# What is the advantage of dynamic memory control?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, stack, difference

For example, I want to make a stack. I can do it in that way, using the dynymic memory control, with `new` and `delete` opereations:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct List
{
    int x; 
    List *Next,*Head; 
};


void Add(int x, List *&MyList)
{
    List *temp=new List; 
    temp->x=x; 
    temp->Next=MyList->Head; 
    MyList->Head=temp; 
}


void Show(List *MyList) 
{
    List *temp=MyList->Head; 

    while (temp!=NULL) 
    {
    cout<<temp->x<<" "; 
    temp=temp->Next; 
    }
}


void ClearList(List *MyList)
    {
    while (MyList->Head!=NULL) 
    {
    List *temp=MyList->Head->Next; 
    delete MyList->Head; 
    MyList->Head=temp; 
}
}

int main()
{


    List *MyList=new List; 


    MyList->Head=NULL; 

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) Add(i,MyList); 
    Show(MyList); 

    ClearList(MyList); 
    delete MyList->Head;
    delete MyList;
}
```

And also I can just make a stack in that way and do anything with it:

```
std::stack<int> MyStack;
```

So, which one is better? What is the advantage of a stack with dynamic memory allocation? In what cases should I use first/second variants?

Comment: std::stack also uses "dynamic memory control" in its implementation.  Necessary to allow the stack to store an arbitrary number of elements.  Its advantage is that you don't have to do it yourself of course.

Comment: [C or C++ dynamic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) (allocated with `malloc` in C or with `new` in C++) is called *heap memory*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The both stacks use dynamically allocated memory for their nodes (though for std::stack it depends on underlying container).
Of course it is better to use standard class. It was already tested and written by qualified programmers and it is flexible enough: you can use several standard containers to implement the stack because standard stack is a container adapter.

In fact you can write your own underlying container for std::stack as for example a wrapper around an array and in this case the whole stack will be placed in the stack memory though its size of course will be fixed.:)

Nevertheless the standard stack also has many drawbacks. For example you can  not use `std::forward_list` as the underlying container. I made a proposal to specialize standard class `std::stack` for `std::forward_list`.

Comment: Everything you said is correct. I just want to add that it is generally not the best idea to use `std::stack<>` when you need a stack. The default container for `std::stack<>` is `std::dequeue<>`. While a dequeue can certainly serve as a stack, it has requirements that make it more complicated than a simple `std::vector<>`. When I need a stack, I simply use `std::vector<>`, `emplace_back()`, `back()`, and `pop_back()`. That's the fastest implementation of a stack you are going to get with the standard C++ library.

Comment: Не подскажешь, как часто вообще приходится сталкиваться с "не-STL" реализацией стека? Просто вариант с выделением памяти вручную, как мне кажется, это "велосипед"...

Comment: @Jack Кроме заданий для студентов я нигде не встречал не STL реализацию стека. :) С другой стороны, я сам не имел дело с C++ проектами. Так что мой опыт не показателен.

Comment: Да вот в том то и дело, что у нас в вузе преподаётся "программирование на C++", но препод в основном пишет примеры в стиле Си, и заставляет создавать собственную реализацию динамических массивов, двусвязных списков, etc. На данном этапе мне сложно оценить, насколько эти  знания пригодятся в будущем. Спасибо за комментарии)

Comment: @Jack Это полезно самостоятельно решать подобные задачи в качестве упражнений.

Comment: @Jack, Vlad, speak _English_ please.

Answer (score 1):

which one is better depends surely on the use case. But generally I would advise you to use the STL implementation of the stack, because it is heavily used and therefore tested perfectly.
Furthermore, you'll get a perfect abstraction of a stack with the STL implementation. 
Second, the STL implementation is also using dynamic memory allocation, so from this point of view there is no difference to your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic memory gives the advantage of adding possible memory leaks and/or segmentation faults to your program.

I only use dynamic memory when forced to. Forcing example: working with a library that uses c-strings for parameters and return values.